# Generate a google drive notification from a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I would like google drive (or drive file stream) to automatically show a notification when a spreadsheet cell reaches a certain value. Is this possible with the spreadsheets api and the google drive api? Furthermore, is it possible to customize the html of this notifications?

I know that the popup dialogs inside spreadsheets are part of the ui, so they can only be triggered by the user (not automatically). If this is the same whit the google drive notifications, are there other ways to make this happen?

Comment: That depends on what kind of notification you would like. I don't think there is a built-in way to do that, but you could install a trigger via Apps Script that will check whether the cell value has reached a certain value and send an email, serve an API endpoint, or what have you, if that's the case. It could be an onEdit trigger if you want to track manual changes to this cell.

Comment: How can I install a trigger that checks whether the cell value has reached a certain value? As I understand, the closest to this would be a onChange trigger but how would you even specify which Cell to consider? My approach would be something like this: 

`=if(A1>0;send_notification();"do nothing")`

And have the function talk between the Spreadsheet API and the Drive API, so that when it is called from the formula inside the cell it activates a notification in Drive.

Comment: If the trigger is an `onEdit`, the triggered function can check the value of the cell thanks to the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit), and send the notification only if the cell value has reached this other value. The issue, from my perspective, would be what kind of notification you want. I don't think the kind of notification you want is available in Drive API. You could use [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push), but I'm not sure it's appropriate for you situation. Would receiving an email be an option?

Comment: You could also serve an API endpoint when the cell value condition was met. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752729/calling-an-api-endpoint-upon-changes-to-any-google-sheets-files/59755245#59755245).

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to poll the spreadsheet via a timebased timer or a trigger from a clientside dialog or webapp using setInterval.